# Creating User in Exchange 2010 with .Net (C# or VB.NET)

Tags: c#, vb.net, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I want to create a .Net application that will create Users and MailBox's in Exchange 2010. I have seen the PowerShell method, but i want to work without that.

Anyone any ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In fact as I know Exchange gets it's user from active directory. This means you can check this link:
[Manage Active Directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C)

Comment: I have Active Directory working fine with .Net. But it doesn't sync with Exchange to create MailBox.